# Import all data from a HTML table, including empty cells

Tags: import, web-access, html

I wanted to create a dataset of all UFO sightings in April of 2018. The 
`AssociationThread` doesn't want to work, because some of the entries are missing value, what is the best way to fix it?

```
dataA1 = Import[
"http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201804.html", {"HTML", 
"Data"}];
dataA2 = Flatten[Rest@dataA1, 1];
dataA3 = 
 Map[AssociationThread[First[dataA1], #] &, dataA2]
Dataset[dataA3]
```

Comment: To be clear, this isn't about data that is `Missing[]`, but rather `Import[XXXX,{"HTML", "Data"}]` giving "tables" that have rows with inconsistent lengths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be clear, this isn't about data that is `Missing[]` (in which case, you would use `DeleteMissing`), but rather `Import[XXXX,{"HTML", "Data"}]` returning "tables" that have rows with inconsistent lengths.

You can solve this by importing `"FullData"` rather than `"Data"`.

```
dataA1 = Import[
  "http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201804.html", {"HTML", 
   "FullData"}]
dataA2 = Flatten[Most@Rest@dataA1[[8]], 1]
dataA3 = Map[AssociationThread[dataA1[[8, 1, 1]], #] &, dataA2];
Dataset[dataA3]
```

What's awkward about this is that there can be many empty tables that you must sift through (as you can see, I have to get the 8th element). However, it works quite well in this case.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not completely sure how "Data" and "FullData" differ. Why do they exist separately?

Comment: @ArtemAnisimov From the [documentation for the "HTML" import/export format](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HTML.html): `"FullData"` imports: "full tabular content, including empty HTML table and list elements". `"Data"` doesn't import empty elements.